# Firebase shows authenticated users even though users where deleted

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I am using firebase admin sdk with nodejs to manage users accounts, specifically, migrating from one firebase to another.
Though the migration ran well, I noticed a problem when I decided to delete all the users that were migrated and run the migration again.

[image: Firebase showing there still are users even though no one is listed]

This is the code that migrates auth users:

```
async saveAuthUsers(authUsers) {
    try {
      const hash = {
        hash: {
          algorithm: 'STANDARD_SCRYPT',
          memoryCost: 1024,
          parallelization: 16,
          blockSize: 8,
          derivedKeyLength: 64
        }
      };
      const userImportResult = await this.firebaseTo.auth().importUsers(authUsers, hash);
      // failed auth users
      if (userImportResult.failureCount) {
        userImportResult.errors.forEach((indexedError) => {
          console.log('User: ' + authUsers[indexedError.index].uid + ' with email: ' + authUsers[indexedError.index].email + ' failed to import ', indexedError.error);
        });
      }

      authUsers.forEach((authUser) => {
        console.log(`Current migrated user uid: ${authUser.uid} email: ${authUser.email}`);

      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

Is there any reason why this could happen?

Comment: Looks likely to just be a console bug. Is that count on the receiving project or the sending project? If it's the receiving project, you can try exporting that one and see if there are user records and, if so, if they are missing any crucial data.

Comment: @Kato that count id is from the receiving project. I ran the following code after deleting all auth users:  await this.firebaseTo.auth().listUsers(size, nextPageToken) to verify if there were any auth users, it returned an empty list though in firebase console it still shows 1-0 of 757479.

Comment: I think you must have ran the migration multiple times resulting in duplication of your users. After you deleted all your users, the duplicate copies remain. Contact [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support) to help you fix this.

Comment: @bojeil thanks for your feedback. I think I have to do so, it just seems strange that the users counter shows users even after being deleted. I mean, shouldn't all users be deleted (even the duplicated ones)?